# Slide effect not working on my website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would really appreciate some help, I have jQuery UI and trying to implement the slide effect to my menu (when menu opens it slides out from the right), however I cant get it to work.

HTML:

```
<!-- nav -->
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbutton">
        <section class="menutext">Menu</section>
        <div class="hamburger">
            <span class="menuline1" style="background:black;"></span>
            <span class="menuline2" style="background:black;"></span>
            <span class="menuline3" style="background:black;"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="mainmenu">  
        <div class="navbutton-close">X
            <?php mainmenu(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- /nav -->
```

css:

```
/* Nav Global */
.hamburger {
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.menuline1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 4px;
}
.menuline2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 12px;
}
.menuline3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
}
.menutext {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbutton-open {
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible; 
}
.navbutton-close {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.navbutton-extend {
    visibility: hidden; 
}
.mainmenu {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(181, 181, 181, 0.54);
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
/* End Nav Global */
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".navbutton").addClass("navbutton-open");
     $(".mainmenu").hide();

     $(".navbutton").click(function(){
           $("a.navbutton").addClass("navbutton-extend");
           $(".mainmenu").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
     });

     $(".navbutton-close").click(function(){
           $(".navbutton").addClass("navbutton-open").removeClass("navbutton-extend");
           $("div.mainmenu").hide();
     });
});
```

Comment: i have posted code i think that is what you was looking.

Answer (score 1):

So this is easy jQuery, from what I gather you want a closed nav to open up left to right (correct me if im wrong).

To do this, set the menu container to have a width of 0. 
On click of the menu button you want to add a class which has the width set (dont do stuff in javaScript you can get away with in CSS)
The transition effect comes from CSS3 transition rule. Transition on width.
Effectively the click event will simply add a class.

Here is a quick example.

https://jsfiddle.net/ovzfkfvf/

```
// Super simple html 
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>

  <div class="menu-container">
    <p>
      This is the menu container
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

// Basic CSS - notice with width 0 on the menu element
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  background:black;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px 0;
}

.btn.active {
  background:green;
}

.menu-container {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:0;
  transition:width 1s cubic-bezier(0,0,0,1);
  color:white;
  background:red;
}

.menu-container.open {width:100%;}

// The click event
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.menu-container').toggleClass('open');
});
```

PS: Format code correctly and include links to fiddles to make it easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code will work for your need

```js
   

 $(".hamburger").click(function(){
  $('.mainmenu').toggle( "slide" );
});
$(".mainmenu").click(function(){
  $(this).toggle( "slide" );
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.menuline1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 4px;
}
.menuline2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 12px;
}
.menuline3 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
}
.menutext {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbutton-open {
    margin-left: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible; 
}
.navbutton-close {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.navbutton-extend {
    visibility: hidden; 
}
.mainmenu {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(181, 181, 181, 0.54);
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbutton">
        <section class="menutext">Menu</section>
        <div class="hamburger">
            <span class="menuline1" style="background:black;"></span>
            <span class="menuline2" style="background:black;"></span>
            <span class="menuline3" style="background:black;"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="mainmenu">  
        <div class="navbutton-close">X
            <?php mainmenu(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```